# Visual Studio 2012 unable to activate Windows Store App

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8

Yesterday while I was working on my Windows 8 App in Visual Studio I ran into an error in Visual Studio:

> Error: Unable To Activate Windows Store App "ff82Aa95f-51e3-4869-a77a-7a9f52af3aea_aqtq9fhtdt8n6!APP" The WWAHOST.exe Process Started But The Acivation Proccess Failed with Error: "Access is Denied.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Hey Loop, thanks very much your idea worked I'm felling very good now Thanks for your support....Great Work

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, double-click **manifest** file and select **Packaging** tab you will find **Package identity** there.

By changing the package identity little bit your app will start to work fine.I have this problem too sometimes. Actual cause I don't know. But it works every time for me.

If original package identity is this "ff82Aa95f-51e3-4869-a77a-7a9f52af3aea_aqtq9fhtdt8n6" then change it to "ff82Aa95f-51e3-4869-a77a-7a9f52af3aea_aqtq9fhtdt8n7" here i have only change last digit **6** to **7**.